# Unit step function differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, physics, differential

Suppose we model a physical phenomenon with a 2nd order linear differential equation:

$a_2$(t)$y''$+$a_1$(t)$y'$+$a_0$(t)$y$=$f(t)$,

where 't' stands for time.

- In choosing an appropriate driving function $f(t)$, suppose we want just the segment of a certain function $g(t)$ for 5≤t<10 only.
- Further, suppose we want this segment to be active for the duration 15≤t<20
- while for 0≤t<15 and 20≤t, we want f(t)=0

describe this input function $f(t)$ using the unit step function.

I think it's just how wordy this question is, but I am completely lost, any help or even just a step in the right direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A step (heaviside) function is defined 
$$u(t)=\begin{cases}0&t<0\\1&t<0\end{cases}$$
To shift the jump right to $t=\alpha>0$ units one need $u(t-\alpha)$. Similarly to shift it left one need $u(t+\alpha)$. To shift it up/down one need $u(t)\pm\alpha$. To scale it one need $\alpha u(t)$. Finally to switch it upside down one need $-u(t)$.

For a range $a\leq t\leq b$ of $g(t)$ you will need 
$$g(t)u(t-a) - g(t)u(t-b)=
\begin{cases}0&t<a\\
g(t) & a \leq t \leq b\\
0 & t\ge b
\end{cases}$$

In the last one you want shifted $g(t)$ at $[a,b]$, i.e. you need $g(t-\alpha)$ instead of  $g(t)$. Note you have $a=15$, $b=20$, $\alpha =10$. Finally
$$g(t-10)u(t-15) - g(t-10)u(t-20)$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I am now asked to find the Laplace Transform of g(t−10)U(t−15)−g(t−10)U(t−20) or at least to describe the form that L{f(t-a)U(t-b)} takes, I'm working on it now and if I figure it out then i will post back up on here. Thanks again! :)

Comment: this would be another question, so post new question and if you need make a link to this one.